# VS2010 not handling "includes" in preprocessor conditions properly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction

I have a fairly large VS2010 C++ solution. There is only one project in the solution so there are no inter-dependencies between projects. The problem is, when I pull an update from GIT, VS2010 is sometimes not smart enough to rebuild translation units that would be affected by the new files that were updated. This results in an executable that inevitably crashes in some bogus way.

This is painful for me because I cannot trust partial builds and end up having to do a full rebuild whenever i jump around in git which is killing productivity.

NOTE: I'm not blaming git in any way, I'm just pointing out my process in case it's relevant.
ALSO NOTE: When I build, i'm right clicking on the project and selecting "Build".

Does anyone know of a way to "debug" this compiler to know why it doesn't notice that it needs to rebuild other files that are dependent on the changes?

EDIT: Upon further investigation, I can rule out my use of GIT as a problem. I can reproduce this by editing a header file that's included in many many places, save it and then run a "Build" which doesn't want to build any new files.

EDIT 2: The issue appears to be related to #defines. I have a header that's only included in ANOTHER header...and it's only included in that header under some conditions which are specified by #defines. So we have #if COND1  #elif COND2  #else < the problem header in question #endif and that's broken. If i take the include out of the else case, it triggers dependencies to compile properly!

Comment: VS determines what to build by comparing the file dates with the dates on the .obj files. Is it possible that git back-dates the files when it gets them?

Comment: Mark, that seems logical but the GIT docs claim that it doesn't restore old timestamps to avoid this problem. https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_isn.27t_Git_preserving_modification_time_on_files.3F

Comment: Macros are clearly a troublemaker here, especially when their values change while compiling.  If the header contains a class declaration that substitutes a class in another header then you'll need to turn off the /Gm Minimum rebuild option.

Comment: I don't have Minimum Rebuild enabled. Also, values of the macros do not change, they are only set in one place in the master header.

Answer (score 1):

I know neither git nor VS2010, but when I've seen this sort of behavior with make-based systems, it's usually because the version control system is pulling a file and giving it the time it was committed (or even the modify time it had when it was committed). The build system then thinks the 'source' file is still older than the 'object' file and fails to rebuild stuff.

See if you can find an option to git to NOT fixup the file times when it does a pull. Instead, you want newly pulled files to have the current time.

I suspect that will fix the issue for you.

Comment: Fascinating...it sounds like that could be it actually. I'll dig a little in that direction.

Comment: Hmm unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the case according to the docs: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_isn.27t_Git_preserving_modification_time_on_files.3F

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is, as you say in the EDIT2, a header file not detected by the dependency checker of VS, you can solve it with the following trick:

- Get a copy of the `touch` and `test` utilities for Windows (for example from the [GNUWin32 site](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm).
- Write a *prebuild command* that copies the modification time from the utracked header to the tracked one, but only if it is newer:

Something like:

```
test.exe untracked.h -nt tracked.h && touch.exe -r untracked.h tracked.h
```

PS: Maybe you can write the same idea using PowerShell, but I don't know how.

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking more for a solution at the compiler level. I've either hit a compiler bug or my code's doing something sketchy at some level that's making the compiler do something equally fishy. My fear in any indirect work around is that it'll just crop up somewhere else in some other form.